# Lumia 930 touch screen stops reponding after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: insider-preview

I just upgraded my Nokia Lumia 930 for Windows 10 for the second time. but after receiving couple of call my touch screen stopped responding. Need to reboot device to get the screen activated. The same thing happens again after couple of calls.The same happen in my previous windows 10 upgrade.then I roll back to 8.1. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried doing a hard reset after the win 10 upgrade?

Comment: Has a only solution: Wait for the next bug-fix build.